# SQL Starting with columns

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns

I have:

```
Id | Timestamp column
---------------------------
1  | 700 (not ten, but simple to read)
2  | 800
3  | 800
4  | 800
5  | 600
```

I get the first 2 records, ordered by timestamp DESC

```
Id | Timestamp column
---------------------------
2  | 800
3  | 800
```

Now, I can't get the next 2 records ordered by timestamp DESC starting with id 3 and timestamp 800

I try:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp < 800 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 2
```

but returns Id 1 and 5, which is not correct.

Try it also:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp <= 800 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 2
```

but returns id 2 and 3, which is again not correct.

Try it also

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp <= 800 AND id > 3 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 2
```

but returns Id 4 and 5, which is again not correct.

And so on.... all I try is not working.

The query should return exactly:

```
Id | Timestamp column
---------------------------
4  | 800
1  | 700
```

I also try to play with order by id, but I can't get it work.

Some help ?

EDIT: I can't explain, but for sure I don't know how many records are already extracted, so I can't use Offset. I just know the last record - id 3 and timestamp 800...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to order by both `timestamp` and `id`, so that you get consistent ordering within all the rows with the same `timestamp`. Then when you do the next query, you use the last `id` as part of the `WHERE` clause.

So the first time it's

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY timestamp DESC, id
LIMIT 2
```

Get the ID and timestamp from the last row of this into `@id` and `@timestamp`, then your next query should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (timestamp = @timestamp AND id > @id) OR (timestamp < @timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC, id
LIMIT 2
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80940c/3)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query

```
Select * 
from table 
where not exists (select * from table where id<=3 and timestamp= 800)
order by id asc, timestamp desc 
limit 2
```